# Can't boot on OS X partition after resizing Windows partition

Tags: bootcamp, startup, partition, efi

I initially had three bootable partitions:

- OS X
- Recovery for OS X
- Bootcamp (Windows 8)

Now, on Windows, I decided to make my Windows partition smaller, reducing its size using the native Disk Manager. I did, leaving some unallocated space at the end of the disk. Then I restarted my macbook while holding 'alt' and I was surprised to find only one bootable partition:

- Bootcamp (Windows 8)

Confused, I decided to revert my changes by re-expanding my Windows partition to its original size. The disk mapping looks just the same as before, except I still can't boot on OS X or Recovery for OS X, because they aren't displayed at all on Startup Manager of my macbook.

[image: four partitions on disk]

How to fix EFI (or whatever is causing the problem) and boot again on OS X?

[*edit: small note, this issue was long time ago... I have reinstalled the whole computer since then*]

Answer (score 1):

Presumably Windows messed up with your OS X boot code.
You have to rebuild this code.
Since OS X tools can not handle a false flagged partition you have to set the correct partition flag and afterwards rebuild the boot code using OS X Disk Utility.

Since you can't boot from the now unaccessible recovery partition you have to have Linux-tools and a second Mac (accessing your messed up hard disk via target mode 2nd stage) or a OS X install DVD/USB-key by the hand.

Let's go:

Download the latest gParted iso file here: [gParted](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/latest/download?source=files)

Burn the iso to a CD or transfer it using the tool of your choice to a USB drive.
For help to create a gParted Live-USB look here: [Live-USB](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/liveusb.php)

Boot your Mac using gParted-Linux.

Go to the gParted-tool. 
(First window will be opened automagically on the desk.)
Select the (probably your first) HFS+ partition and do the right click.
Be aware, this is not the first 200 MB EFI-partition!!!

Now edit the partition info.

- Tick the square for the msft-type.
- Remove the mark. Do not mark any of the available marks.
- Write out the changes.

Leave the tool and reboot into a OS X-Install-DVD or prepared OS X install-USB-key (or as forementioned connect your dead Mac-HDD to the other Mac via Firewire or TB now accessing the disk in target mode)

Open OS X Disk Utility.

- Tick on the Apple HDD, let Disk Utility repair the partition layout.
- Check the OS X-partition too and reboot into your OS X again.

Hold the alt-key and choose the OS X boot volume.
Be happy.

for background stuff from the sources please check search for:

1. [Apple tech notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2166/_index.html)
2. [steelpangolin](https://steelpangolin.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/invalid-bs_jmpboot-in-boot-block-000000/)

or search for "apple tech notes tn2166" or "steelpangolin invalid-bs_jmpboot-in-boot-block-000000/"

Update:

1. this is for hdd that has NO hybrid partition only, sorry otherwise this is not for you
2. please be prepared prior to any further coming desaster

so

- make a bootable copy of the stock or newly installed OSX (minimum space required ca. 10GB) to an external drive

or

- create a bootable setup-stick of the setup-image (contained in any OSX Install.app) 
  This will speed up the recovery and makes you more independent from huge downloads  esp. over slow lines.

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "no hybrid partition"! No hMBR/pMBR or with other words GPT-only?

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend trying rEFIt? It's a boot loader for EFI partition tables. You can put it on a USB stick and boot from there - it may be able to recognise the OS X partition or otherwise repair your EFI table.

You can [download rEFIt here](http://refit.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

1. Reboot the Mac into Single User Mode by holding Command+S during boot
2. At the command prompt, type:

   ```
   /sbin/fsck -fy
   ```
3. When fsck is complete, type “exit” or “reboot” to reboot
4. Boot the Mac as usual, verify the disk again in Disk Utility, and partition as usual